# Add a redirect from arqade.stackexchange.com to gaming.stackexchange.com

Tags: feature-request, new-users, domain-name

I'm fairly new to this site, and whenever I'm talking about the site I call it '**Arqade**'. A lot of times I will type `arqade.stackexchange.com` into the address bar, but I get a message that it [couldn't find arqade.stackexchange.com](http://arqade.stackexchange.com/). I then search through sites in the Stack Exchange drop-down list and finally find this site.

I think it would be good to have an auto-redirect from `arqade.stackexchange.com` to `gaming.stackexchange.com`. What do you think?

Comment: Just go to http://arqade.com :D

Comment: Also searching `arqade` in Google ;).

Comment: No. Bad. That's what the URL bar is for

Comment: I don't know if the redirection is necessary, but I have been confused between the use of "gaming" vs "arqade" before. Not a huge fan of having both...

Comment: Related: [Why doesn't Arqade use it's named URL when other sites like AskUbuntu do?](//meta.arqade.com/q/15601/28182)

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure this is a good idea.

Where do you draw the line?

You suggest `arqade.stackexchange.com` redirecting to `gaming.stackexchange.com`,
but this is only based on a new user assumption.  Now you have discovered the correct URL all is right in the world!

This will only fix problems for new users, and I presume only when typing in the address as `arqade.stackexchange.com`.  What should happen if someone types the following into their address bar:

- `arqade` as `arcade`?
- Sub-pages such as https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions
- With and without a `www` prefix
- The meta site (i.e. should meta.arqade.stackexchange.com also redirect?)

I would only reserve redirects when there is good reason for a user to be redirected.  For example, a company re-brands itself or buys out another company and wishes to re-point users to a different location.

Back-patching redirects for this purpose brings more confusion, work and potential bugs/criticism of edge cases (e.g. "Why doesn't the meta also redirect?" etc).

It seems far easier to accept that the address typed was wrong, and accept that the address doesn't match the name of the Stack Exchange.  Typing `gaming` is arguably a more logical approach than typing a corruption of the word `arcade`.

Comment: Sub pages and the www shouldn't be a problem with redirection I wouldn't think.The other two points make more sense. Of course `arcade` shouldn't be handled, it's a clear misspelling. And meta probably would have to redirect, from a UX POV, but would practically be unnecessary. All things considered, it's just slightly unfortunate that the actual name of the site is not what the URL actually needs. Basically, the small amount of confusion is probably not with the effort to change anything.

Comment: I would expect the domain to redirect when spelled arqade, and that's it. This doesn't seem like a real objection.

Answer (score -5):

Press the little arrow, next to the "Stack Exchange" logo, and you'll see a list of Stack Exchange sites. Also note that the URL adress is the following:
      "gaming.stackexchange.com"
Even if the site is called Arqade, it's URL adress name is different.

Comment: *"Even if the site is called Arqade, it's URL adress name is different."* True, but I see why OP does not like this. I don't either. It's "confusing", but I don't see it changing anytime soon.